# wp_mail function not working in WordPress Plugin Boilerplate

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-mail

I am creating a plugin using WordPress plugin boilerplate (https://wppb.me/), I have create a separate file for sending emails under /admin/partials/ directory. but wordpress throw error when I am using wp_mail function in this file. any solution for this?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_mail()

Answer (score 0):

If it's undefined, that means you're trying to run `wp_mail()` before it is loaded.  Whatever you've hooked it to is too early.  Hook your process to a later action.  Essentially, anything like `plugins_loaded` or later.